# What is better approach for saving configuration data in php?

Tags: php, serialization, drupal, blob

I am interested now a little bit fin drupal and I saw it saves many configuration options to db like BLOB (I think they are serialized php variables like array).

- Why drupal don't use saving conf. options to php file and then simple include it?
- What do you think is better approach for saving conf. data: DB or file and then simple include?
- Maybe filesystem is faster then socket and db?

Comment: Its personal preference, tho its easier to store in db then to worry about wrongly set file permissions ect

Comment: Krab, if you look for orientation because of specific reasons, you should name them. Otherwise the answer is just: It depends. Also please remember that the filesystem *is* a database.

Answer (score 3):

Storing configuration information in a central location like a database allows load balancing on the front end. If you were using conf files and had 2 load balanced web servers, you would need to make sure the conf files on each server stay in sync. A database is an easy way to centralize the configuration, and replicate it if needed.

Comment: How so? Did the question indicate a multi server setup? Why would repeated sql queries profile better than a file share? -- You should stress the easy part, the performance guess is hardly a given.

Comment: Reasonable point. They asked why Drupal doesn't save to conf. Drupal is designed to scale to a multi-server setup. As for performance, chances are there is already a db connection, so an extra query would be quick. A file requires a stat call, permissions check and a file read. Over NFS, add a network call. Both db and file have their advantages/disadvantages.